# Why does this code not show an alert?

Tags: iphone

The following code should show a UIAlertView in response to a button being clicked in a UIActionSheet, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  Does someone have an idea as to why this is?

```
-(void)actionsheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionsheet willDissmissAtButtonIndex:(NSInteger)
buttonindex{
    if(buttonindex =[actionsheet cancelButtonIndex]){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"welcome" 
        message:@"thanku for watching" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"bye" 
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is an = missing :)

**EDIT**
check this

```
 if(buttonindex == [actionsheet cancelButtonIndex]){
```